# oracle - grant all privileges to schema

Tags: mysql, oracle, oracle-11g

i've used mysql before and i'm now switching to oracle.

I've already created a user in oracle. Now i want to give it "all privileges" for a schema.

In mysql i can give all privileges (DML/DDL) for a schema "mySchema" **without grant** (DCL) like this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mySchema.* TO 'user';
```

What's the oracle equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite the same:

```
GRANT ALL ON yourSchema.* TO (...)
```

whereas `(...)` is `PUBLIC`, `'username'` (optionally followed by `IDENTIFIED BY 'password'`)  or a specific role you defined earlier.

See here for a more detailed explanation: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9013.htm

Comment: GRANT ANY ON testschema.* TO 'JMW'; fails! With ORA-00990 for ANY

Comment: Sorry, seems like "ANY" isn't (no longer?) valid - it's 'ALL' as well. I'll update the answer.

Comment: BS. Doesn't work on Oracle 10g2, as your link indicates